# How do I understand the concept of eigenspace?

Tags: linear-algebra

Like for example, there are three distinct eigenvalues and the matrix P that diagonalizes A is \begin{pmatrix}0&1&2\\ \:2&0&3\\ \:3&4&0\end{pmatrix}

So, can I say \begin{pmatrix}3&4&0\\ 2&0&3\\ \:0&1&2\end{pmatrix} doesn't diagonalize A because the eigenvectors are linearly dependent.

Sorry, I need example to understand the concept better. Hope someone can clarify.

Comment: To make your question better, what is $A$ and what is $P$ (in your question you seem to be working with a very specific example, so tell us clearly which matrix is which). Regarding concepts: the first step is always understanding definitions, and before you can understand definitions, you need to KNOW the definitions (step 0 :) ). So, write down the definition of eigenvalue,eigenvector of a matrix, and then ask something specific (because as it stands, even if I want to help you I don't know what the issue is)

Comment: Worth a look: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PFDu9oVAE-g

Comment: Thanks for replying. @ peek-a-boo , In this case, A is the 1st matrix while P is the matrix that is PAP^-1=D. So, P I am referring to the 2nd matrix as an example.

Answer (score 0):

Your "example" is a bit difficult to understand, but the most reasonable question I could extract is this:

> Suppose that $A$ is a matrix with three distinct eigenvalues, and that $P$ diagonalizes $A$ (so that $PAP^{-1}$ is diagonal).  If we rearrange the rows of $P$, do we end up with another matrix that diagonalizes $A$, or should we say that the rearranged $P$ doesn't diagonalize $A$ "because the eigenvectors are linearly dependent".

The answer to this question is: if $PAP^{-1}$ is diagonal and if $Q$ is obtained by rearranging the rows of $P$, then $QAQ^{-1}$ will also be diagonal.  In particular, $PAP^{-1}$ will be diagonal if and only if every row $r$ of $P$ satisfies $rA = \lambda r$, which in other words means that $A^Tr^T = \lambda r^T$, i.e. $r^T$ is an eigenvector of $A^T$.  If every row of $P$ is an eigenvector of $A^T$, then every row of $Q$ will also be an eigenvector of $A$.

---

All that being said, this is a strange question to ask for someone trying to "understand the concept of eigenspace".  Perhaps this will help.

Typically, the phrase "$P$ diagonalizes $A$" means that $D = P^{-1}AP$ is a diagonal matrix; notice that the $P^{-1}$ is on the left side of $A$ here.  $P$ will diagonalize $A$ if and only if

1. it is invertible, and
2. every column of $P$ is an eigenvector of $A$.

You might notice that with this definition, rearranging the **columns** of $P$ gives us another matrix that diagonalizes $A$, but rearranging the rows as we did earlier will not necessarily do the same.

So, what does the fact that an $n \times n$ $A$ is diagonalizable tell us about $A$? Notice that for $P$ to be invertible, it needs to have linearly independent columns.  Since its columns also need to be eigenvectors of $A$, $A$ needs to have a linearly independent set of $n$ eigenvectors.  On the other hand, if $A$ has a linearly independent set of $n$ eigenvectors, the we could use these to build the matrix $P$.

In other words, $A$ is diagonalizable if and only if $A$ has a complete, linearly independent set of eigenvectors.